# Combine multiple JSON rows into one JSON object in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I want to combine the following JSON from multiple rows into one single JSON object as a row.

```
{"Salary": ""}
{"what is your name?": ""}
{"what is your lastname": ""}
```

**Expected output**

```
{
  "Salary": "",
  "what is your name?": "",
  "what is your lastname": ""
}
```

Comment: Please do **not** post sample data as images. You will get more help if you provide sample data as formatted text as shown [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) or even better as a little SQL script with `create table` and the `insert into` statements.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With only built-in functions, you need to expand the rows into key/value pairs and aggregate that back into a single JSON value:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(t.k, t.v)
from the_table, jsonb_each(ob) as t(k,v);
```

If your column is of type `json` rather than `jsonb` you need to cast it:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(t.k, t.v)
from the_table, jsonb_each(ob::jsonb) as t(k,v);
```

A slightly more elegant solution is to define a new aggregate that does that:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE jsonb_combine(jsonb) 
(
    SFUNC = jsonb_concat(jsonb, jsonb),
    STYPE = jsonb
);
```

Then you can aggregate the values directly:

```
select jsonb_combine(ob)
from the_table;
```

(Again you need to cast your column if it's `json` rather than `jsonb`)

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=aad32d85449c7b48d61c2faee2e4adc0)

Comment: This should be first in a google search, I had to look for 10 other links before I found this simple solution. Thank you very much, you probably saved me 3-4 hours of refactoring :)